# Set focus on EditText when fragment changes

Tags: android, android-fragments, kotlin

I have two fragments with two EditText, I want to keep the focus on the second EditText (Fragment two) when I change from fragment one to fragment two with the first EditText focused. I have a focuschangelistener controling the first EditText focus but I don't know how to check the first EditText focus when the fragment changes because It always return false on the second fragment (I supose that the fragment view clears the focus on detach).

Right now I have a focus listener on fragment create view:

```
etEmail?.setOnFocusChangeListener { v, hasFocus ->
        (activity as SessionActivity).animation() //this is an animation
        isFocused = hasFocus //this is my bool status check
    }
```

And in the second fragment I call the companion to check the state:

```
Log.d("FOCUS", hadFocus.toString())
```

Comment: Hi so just to clarify, you want EditText 1 and 2 to have the same focus when changing Fragments? So if EditText 1 is in focus and you change to Fragment 2, EditText 2 should also be in focus?

Answer (score 0):

use this in onResume:

```
onResume(){
  super.onResume();
  findViewById(R.id.SecondEditText).requestFocus();

}
```

Better is to find a view in `onCreate` and save it in instance variable then call `requestFocus` on that variable in `onResume` to remove delay to find view every time in `onResume` especially on multi-windows which `onResume` calls on every window size changes